# How to get feed output of a grunt task to another grunt task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, gruntjs, grunt-exec

I'm not sure if grunt can do this. I have two grunt tasks that I want to run. The first task is to create a mock post and the second is to run `penthouse` task to inline css. Any hacky way is welcome.

This is the `exec` task that I have to run to create a blog post in WordPress.

```
    exec: {
        create_mock: {
            cmd: 'cd ~/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart && vagrant ssh -c \'sh /srv/www/wp-content/themes/vip/the-theme/bin/mock-post.sh\'',
            callback: function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                grunt.log.write('stdout: ' + stdout); // This is the url of the created post.
            }

        }
    },
```

The output is the url that the blog post was created and I have this `penthouse` task to run which I need to feed in the url that this task will look to get all the above-the-fold css.

```
   penthouse: {
        singular: {
            outfile: 'assets/css/inline/_singular.css',
            css: 'assets/css/theme.css',
            minify: true,
            url: $URL, // << I want to feed in the url from the previous task to here.
            width: 1300,
            height: 900
        }
    },
```

The hacky way I can think of is to save the out to a file and read that in `penthouse` task but I think there's must be a better way to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [grunt.config.set](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.get) to set the value directly (or to another property and using it with [grunt.template](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) if you need to use the value multiple times.)

```
 exec: {
    create_mock: {
        cmd: 'cd ~/MyProjects/project/vip-quickstart && vagrant ssh -c \'sh /srv/www/wp-content/themes/vip/the-theme/bin/mock-post.sh\'',
        callback: function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            grunt.config.set("penthouse.singular.url", stdout);
        }

    }
},
```